# Add one or more arguments to \caption

Tags: captions

I would like to add an argument to `\caption`, so that I can add a title to the table, figure or note. Why do I get an error if I modify the definition like I show you below?

```
\documentclass[nofonts]{tufte-handout}

\usepackage{booktabs}    

\makeatletter

%%
% Format the captions in a style similar to the sidenotes

\long\def\@caption#1[#2]#3{%
  \par%
  \addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}%
    {\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #2}}%
  \begingroup%
    \@parboxrestore%
    \if@minipage%
      \@setminipage%
    \fi%
    \@tufte@caption@font\@tufte@caption@justification%
    \noindent\csname fnum@#1\endcsname: \ignorespaces#3\par%
    %\@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #3}\par
  \endgroup}

\makeatother    

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
    \footnotesize%
    \begin{tabular}{lcr}
        \toprule
        Heading & Style & Size \\
        \midrule
        Part & roman & 1 \\
        Chapter & italic & 2 \\
        Section & italic & 11\\
        Subsection & italic & 111 \\
        Paragraph & italic & 10/14 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Fonts}{These are\dots}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

Why can't I just modify the definition like this?

```
\long\def\@caption#1[#2]#3#4{%
  \par%
  \addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}%
    {\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #2}}%
  \begingroup%
    \@parboxrestore%
    \if@minipage%
      \@setminipage%
    \fi%
    \@tufte@caption@font\@tufte@caption@justification%
    \noindent\textsc{#3} \ignorespaces#4\par%
    %\@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #3}\par
  \endgroup}
```

---

Error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.158 \end{table}

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.158 \end{table}

I was expecting to see `<', `=', or `>'. Didn't.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.158 \end{table}

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It has something to do with the table environment. Se my updated question.

Comment: And what should the new argument do?

Comment: @egreg I just wanted to create something like a "label" for the all the material that goes in the margin. Instead of Table 1: This table is about... I wanted to try something new like Title: description... where Title is the title or label of the material (e.g. table, picture, note etc.). Am I making myself clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The internal macro `\@tufte@caption` reads the final arguments of `\caption`.
The following example uses the last argument `#4` as the caption text and puts the type of caption (`Fonts`) in macro `\my@caption@type`. Then this can be used inside `\@caption` with its normal arguments (`#1[#2]#3`).

Also the type (`Fonts`) is put in the list of tables instead of the number. Since additional space is needed, `\@tufte@lof@line` is adjusted accordingly:

```
\documentclass[nofonts]{tufte-handout}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\makeatletter

\long\def\@caption#1[#2]#3{%
  \par%
  \addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}%
  %  {\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #2}}%
    {\protect\numberline{\textsc{\my@caption@type}}{\ignorespaces #2}}%
  \begingroup
    \@parboxrestore
    \if@minipage
      \@setminipage
    \fi
    \@tufte@caption@font\@tufte@caption@justification
    \noindent\textsc{\my@caption@type} \ignorespaces#3\par
    %\@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #3}\par
  \endgroup
}

\long\def\@tufte@caption[#1][#2]#3#4{%
  \gdef\my@caption@type{#3}%
  \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}%
    {\gdef\@tufte@stored@shortcaption{#4}}%
    {\gdef\@tufte@stored@shortcaption{#1}}%
  \gsetlength{\@tufte@caption@vertical@offset}{-#2}%
  \gdef\@tufte@stored@caption{#4}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \renewcommand*{\@tufte@lof@line}[2]{%
    % #1 is the figure/table number and its caption text
    % #2 is the page number on which the figure/table appears
    \leftskip 0.0em
    \rightskip 0em 
    \parfillskip 0em plus 1fil
    \parindent 0.0em
    \@afterindenttrue
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \leavevmode
    % Increase space for the "number"
    \settowidth{\@tempdima}{\textsc{Fonts}\enspace}% largest term
    \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
    \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
    {#1}\nobreak\qquad\nobreak#2% 
    \par%
  }%
  \listoftables
\endgroup

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering  
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tabular}{lcr}
        \toprule
        Heading & Style & Size \\
        \midrule
        Part & roman & 1 \\
        Chapter & italic & 2 \\
        Section & italic & 11\\
        Subsection & italic & 111 \\
        Paragraph & italic & 10/14 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}  
\caption{Fonts}{These are\dots}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: What is the purpose of `\expandafter` here? If I remove it, I can't see any difference...

Comment: @FormlessCloud I have removed it, it was a leftover from a previous version.

Comment: This return an error if you use it within the `margintable` environment...

Comment: @FormlessCloud There are many packages that deal with captions, redefine internals, ..., that can conflict with other code redefining internals.

Comment: Okay don't worry, I just wanted to let you know. I'll take care of it `:)`